# How to preserve colours when colour metadata is "unknown"

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, automation, video-encoding, color-space

I often need to scale up many files with `unknown` color metadata (probably because FFmpeg itself was dropping that metadata until [very recently](https://superuser.com/a/1670018/323079)):

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_streams "input.mp4" | grep color

color_range=tv
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
```

No matter what I do to try and preserve the colours in these files, nothing works to prevent the colours from shifting, usually coming out darker than the input.

I've already tried:

1. Setting all four color metadata options (`-colorspace`, `-color_trc`, `-color_primaries`, `-color_range`) to all of their possible values for PAL, NTSC and HD inputs (`bt470bg`, `smpte170m` and `bt709` respectively)
2. Automatically converting the colorspace as part of the scale by adding `in_color_matrix=auto:out_color_matrix=<COLORSPACE>`, where  is either `bt470`, `smpte170m` or `bt709`
3. Explicitly converting the colorspace as part of the scale by adding `in_color_matrix=<COLORSPACE>:out_color_matrix=bt709`, where  is either `bt470`, `smpte170m` or `bt709`

After all of this, I'm still left none the wiser as to how the hell colour works in FFmpeg and what I'm meant to be doing *just* to get my colour to look as it does in the original input.

Here is the (simplified) FFmpeg command that I'm running as part of a larger script, most of which is *probably* irrelevant to the issue but which I've included in case it *isn't*:

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner \
-i "input.webm" -i "outro.mp4" -loop 1 -i "watermark.png" \
-movflags +faststart+write_colr \ 
-filter_complex \
"color=black:16x16:d=780[base];
[0:v]scale=1922:'max(1080,ih)':flags=lanczos:in_color_matrix=auto:out_color_matrix=bt709[v0];
[1:v]scale=1922:'max(1080,ih)':flags=lanczos,fade=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[v1];
[2:v]lut=a=val*0.7,fade=in:st=15:d=3:alpha=1,fade=out:st=775:d=3:alpha=1[v2];
[base][v0]scale2ref[base][v0];
[base][v0]overlay[tmp];
[tmp][v1]overlay,setsar=1[tmp2];
[v2][tmp2]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih*0.07[watermark_scaled][video]
[video][watermark_scaled]overlay=80:50:shortest=1:format=rgb[outv];
[0:a]afade=out:st=778:d=2[0a];
[0a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[outa]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -c:v libx264 -crf 15 -c:a libopus \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -colorspace bt709 -color_trc bt709 -color_primaries bt709 -color_range tv "output.mp4"
```

Comment: Have a look at  [link](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/28889/ffmpeg-does-not-preserve-colors-after-resizing) .

Comment: @EricMarceau This is not relevant to the question being asked - as already mentioned in the question, I have tried every combination of the usual solutions for preserving colour. This is specifically a problem of dealing with files where there is no colorspace to normalise (i.e. a colorspace of `unknown`).

Comment: Does it give you a color space when you look a the file properties?  If not, then you might want to consider this [link] (https://www.rescuedigitalmedia.com/fix-mp4-header-corruption).